# How to load a delimitted string into an array in unix

Tags: arrays, unix

PFB the scenario
I have a File

```
 John,peter,30,Engineer
 Ann,sam,28,Nurse
```

I want to iterate through each line and put each line into an array.

```
ar[0]=john
a[1]=peter
a[2]=30
a[3]=Engineer
```

Then I do some  process with these then again go for the second line..
Can some one please give some idea..
I tries with the  below code and tried to load the first column, but didnt work

```
while read line
do
ar[1]=echo $line | cut -f1 -d','
done < input.txt
```

Comment: How about using `awk`? `awk -F, '{print $2, $3, $4, $1}' the-file`

Comment: if you're reading **and** writing data to files, look at `awk` programming lang. It will be easier to read, and much more efficient; only 1 process (usually) for the whole file , rather than N processes per line of text; so ... much faster processing. Good luck.